# .NET MVC Ajax.BeginForm displaying message before Success or Failure result

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ajax form in my .NET MVC application like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "User", new { area = "UserSettings" }, new
AjaxOptions
{
   HttpMethod = "POST",
   OnSuccess = "ShowMessage('Password successfully changed')"

}, null))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Password", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })<br />
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PasswordConfirm, new { placeholder = "Confirm password", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })<br />
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
}
```

It's essentially a form to change a password... Now as you can see I have defined a ShowMessage method in a script tag outside of this form which I then call here...

My question here is, in the meantime before the server processes users' post request, and before displaying success or failure message... How can I display something to user in UI using this method?

Like a loading animation or something like that? Is this doable, if so, can someone help me out ?

Comment: In `AjaxOptions` you have `LoadingElementId` property you can use that.

Comment: Not sure about `Ajax.BeginForm` but normally you'd add a bit of javascript:  `$("#ChangePassword").on("submit", function() { $("#loader").show(); });`  where loader is a div with an animated gif

Comment: @User987 : I think you need to call only function like =>OnSuccess = "ShowMessage" and make this jquery function and write message into this function

Comment: you can find all ajaxoptions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions(v=vs.118).aspx  (edit: What @Curiousdev said at the same time :) )